# Where is racket/match in its repo?

Tags: racket

I am doing some research on pattern matching for my own language and am wondering how Racket implements it. I am not that familiar with the language and am having difficulty finding my way through [its source](https://github.com/racket). I want to look at the code where it is written.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the pattern matcher is here:

```
https://github.com/racket/racket/tree/master/racket/collects/racket/match
```

The paper on the implementation "Extensible Pattern Matching in an Extensible Language" by Sam Tobin-Hochstadt is here:

```
http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/samth/match-ifl-full.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Every imported identifiers that is written in Racket can be inspected by right clicking on the identifier and selecting "Open Defining File".

[image: How to open defining file]

You'll eventually find yourself stumbled because the option to open defining file isn't there. eg. `cons` don't have it. The reason is that they are primitives written in C and it miraculously comes out of [`#%kernel`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/running-sa.html?q=%23%25kernel#(idx._(gentag._383._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl)))). To see that you'll need to find it by [searching racket sources](https://github.com/racket/racket/tree/master/racket/src/racket/src)